# Trouble in biber with "ḥʼḤ"

Tags: biblatex, biber, input-encodings, characters, arabic

I am facing issues with special characters in biber. Specifically, this is about "ʼ", "ḥ" and "Ḥ". These are used for Arabic transcription.

I have tried rendering this with LuaLaTeX instead of PDFLaTeX, this solved the issue insofar as it renders the document, but the "ʼ" is replaced by a rectangle in the document.

I have also tried adding `bibencoding = ascii` and `texencoding = ascii`. Both resulted in the document not rendering.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[american]{babel}
    \usepackage{csquotes}
    \usepackage[backend=biber,
                bibencoding=utf8,
                language=auto,
                style=authoryear
                sorting=nyt, 
                maxbibnames=10,
                natbib=true, 
                idembib=false]{biblatex}
    
    \begin{filecontents*}{ref.bib}
    @book{suhrawardiPhilosophieErleuchtungHikmat2011a,
      title = {Philosophie der Erleuchtung =: Hikmat al-ishraq},
      shorttitle = {Philosophie der Erleuchtung},
      author = {Suhrawardī, Yaḥyá ibn Ḥabash},
      editor = {Sinai, Nicolai},
      date = {2011},
      publisher = {{Verlag der Weltreligionen}},
      location = {{Berlin}},
      isbn = {978-3-458-70032-6},
      keywords = {Early works to 1800,Sufism},
      langid = {german},
      pagetotal = {469},
      translator = {Sinai, Nicolai}
    }
    
    @book{avicennaMetaphysicsHealingParallel2004,
      title = {The metaphysics of The healing: a parallel English-Arabic text = al-Ilahīyāt min al-Shifāʼ},
      shorttitle = {The metaphysics of The healing},
        author = {Avicenna},
        editor = {Marmura, Michael E.},
        date = {2004},
        publisher = {{Brigham Young University Press}},
        location = {{Provo, UT}},
        isbn = {978-0-934893-77-0},
        keywords = {Early works to 1800,Islamic philosophy,Metaphysics},
        langid = {eng ara},
        pagetotal = {441},
        series = {Islamic translation series},
        translator = {Marmura, Michael E.}
    }
    \end{filecontents*}
    
    \addbibresource{ref.bib}
    
    \begin{document}
        \title{Some title}
        \author{}
        \date{}
        
        \maketitle
        
    \nocite{avicennaMetaphysicsHealingParallel2004}
\nocite{suhrawardiPhilosophieErleuchtungHikmat2011a}
    
        \printbibliography[]
    \end{document}
```

I have also looked at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251261/input-encoding-error-after-upgrading-from-biber-1-9-to-biber-2-1) and [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/480740/inputenc-error-on-special-character-in-bib-file). They are related, but don't offer a working soloution.

Furthermore, my `ref.bib` file is created by Zotero, so I would much prefer not having to change its contents.

Comment: Not that it matters a great deal, but in this constellation this is not actually a problem that only occurs with `biblatex` or Biber. The same error messages can be reproduced if you just say `Suhrawardī, Yaḥyá ibn Ḥabash al-Ilahīyāt min al-Shifāʼ` in the document body directly and don't load or use `biblatex` at all.

Comment: The easiest way around the problem, IMHO, is to use a font that has the character, and not "build" the character. Try using fontspec + an appropriate font (e.g., Gentium or Brill, but any font that has the glyph will suffice.)

Comment: @BlackBird this is good advice, I did not realize that the font causes this problem.

Comment: @BlackBird however, I can't manage to change the font. Can you write an answer expanding on this soloution?

Comment: It's as easy as using a font package of a font that has those glyphs (`\usepackage{gentium}`, or `libertine`, or `ebgaramond` etc.) or using `\usepackage{fontspec}` `\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}` and compile with `xelatex` or `lualatex` (be sure to remove the packages `inputenc` and `fontenc`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can help LaTeX and provide the representation of the unknown characters.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{suhrawardiPhilosophieErleuchtungHikmat2011a,
  title = {Philosophie der Erleuchtung =: Hikmat al-ishraq},
  shorttitle = {Philosophie der Erleuchtung},
  author = {Suhrawardī, Yaḥyá ibn Ḥabash},
  editor = {Sinai, Nicolai},
  date = {2011},
  publisher = {{Verlag der Weltreligionen}},
  location = {{Berlin}},
  isbn = {978-3-458-70032-6},
  keywords = {Early works to 1800,Sufism},
  langid = {german},
  pagetotal = {469},
  translator = {Sinai, Nicolai}
}

@book{avicennaMetaphysicsHealingParallel2004,
  title = {The metaphysics of The healing: a parallel English-Arabic text = al-Ilahīyāt min al-Shifāʼ},
  shorttitle = {The metaphysics of The healing},
  author = {Avicenna},
  editor = {Marmura, Michael E.},
  date = {2004},
  publisher = {{Brigham Young University Press}},
  location = {{Provo, UT}},
  isbn = {978-0-934893-77-0},
  keywords = {Early works to 1800,Islamic philosophy,Metaphysics},
  langid = {eng ara},
  pagetotal = {441},
  series = {Islamic translation series},
  translator = {Marmura, Michael E.}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  bibencoding=utf8,
  language=auto,
  style=authoryear,
  sorting=nyt, 
  maxbibnames=10,
  natbib=true, 
%  idembib=false
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{02BC}{'}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{1E24}{\d{H}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{1E25}{\d{h}}

\begin{document}
\title{Some title}
\author{}
\date{}

\maketitle

\nocite{avicennaMetaphysicsHealingParallel2004}
\nocite{suhrawardiPhilosophieErleuchtungHikmat2011a}

\printbibliography[]
\end{document}
```

[image]

How do you get the codes? Look in the log file when you get the error!

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ʼ (U+02BC)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.65 \printbibliography[]

?

! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ḥ (U+1E25)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.65 \printbibliography[]

?

! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character Ḥ (U+1E24)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
```

Alternatively, do

```
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newunicodechar{ʼ}{'}
\newunicodechar{Ḥ}{\d{H}} % \d is dot under accent
\newunicodechar{ḥ}{\d{h}}
```

Comment: While this solves the issue for now, it does not seem to be a real soloution, since the issue might just come up again with a different symbol. How does one find the hexa-decimal codes you are using?

Comment: @Floris You find them in the log file! I'll add something.