# Unicode Character Combining Diaeresis U+0308 (and other combined accents)

Tags: unicode, accents

Is there a way to set up LaTeX such that the variants of accented letters that result from using separate Unicode characters for the accents, like `U+0308` for umlaut/diaeresis, will work automatically?

When integrating text from different sources generated on different platforms, such variants come in and generate the error `Unicode character ̈ (U+0308) not set up for use with LaTeX`. Or is replacement by 'proper' accented characters the only choice?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
äöü% actually six characters, with U+0308 after each letter

should be

äöü
\end{document}
```

Beware: Some editors modify the characters when cut/pasting them. `vi` does not modify the pasted characters, `emacs` does.

`pdflatex` generates the error

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ̈ (U+0308)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

Comment: Such combining characters are behind the base character and pdftex can't go back. If you want to use them you will have to switch to an unicode engine.

Comment: Similar question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/79333/82917. 9 years ago but I don't believe that something has changed. (How could it?)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks, `lualatex` and `xelatex` work. I know you prefer, for such simple things, comments instead of answers, but your hint is not among the answers in the other thread, and for many applications the engine does not matter. So would you mind copying your comment to the answer field?

Comment: @campa Thanks for the pointer, this is a near duplicate.

Comment: @gernot David added the comment to his answer in the duplicate.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I [always do what I'm told](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59586601#59586601)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thx.